# How do i find out lines of a file that are not present in another file?

Tags: scripts

I have two files A and B.

I want to find out which lines of file B are not present in the file A.

How do I do this? The lines can be at any position in file A

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file

Answer (score 5):

Simply

```
grep -vxf A B
```

If you want the line number of the non-matching lines also:

```
grep -nvxf A B
```

If B has multiple non-matching identical lines, and you only want to print out the identical lines once, then

```
grep -vxf A B | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 3):

you can sdiff command. 
 Usage: `sdiff file1.txt file2.txt`

you can have the lines any where.

What are the uncommon lines are there they will be indicated with `>` symbol. Look at the below image.
Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You say lines can be at any position, but if position is not important to you (just want to know the differences), use `comm`:

> ```
>    Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.
>
>    With  no  options,  produce  three-column  output.  Column one contains
>    lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to  FILE2,  and
>    column three contains lines common to both files.
> ```

It requires files to be sorted, luckily `sort` can help with that. You can `sort A > A.sorted` to sort it, do something similar with B, and then:

```
comm -1 -3 A.sorted B.sorted
```

this will print "lines unique to FILE2" which in this case is B.sorted.

You can also do the sort inline, the command is a bit more cumbersome to type but you'd save a few steps:

```
comm -1 -3 <(sort A) <(sort B)
```